# Problema con suma y comprobación de caracteres en C

Tags: c, funciones, caracteres

Hola estoy hace un tiempo tratando de resolver este problema que me plantearon es con funciones pero estaba probando primero encontrar como solucionarlo para después convertirlo en función

El problema consta de pedir 2 caracteres al usuario y decirle cuantos caracteres de diferencia tienen entre si

comprobar si este se encuentra en un rango de a y z sin distinguir de mayúsculas y minúsculas

y como ultimo debe de informar un error si lo que se ingresa no es un carácter del abecedario

adjunto el código que hice hasta ahora

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int cont=0;
    char caracter1,caracter2;

    printf("Ingrese un caracter: ");
    scanf(" %c",&caracter1);

     printf("Ingrese otro caracter: ");
    scanf(" %c",&caracter2);

    for (char car='a';caracter1<caracter2; car++){
        cont++;    
    }
    printf("%i\n",cont);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Les agradecería mucho su ayuda  desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Y cual es el problema que tienes con el código que muestras?

Comment: Estoy seguro de haber leído la misma pregunta hace unos días.

Comment: Puedes incluir el header de `ctype.h`, tiene muchas funciones útiles. Te dejo un link de referencia para que intentes y no tengas que decirle a tu profesor que alguien más lo hizo por ti http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/

Comment: El problema es que el for no inicia y el programa queda estancado 
lo que plante fue usar el for usado a y z como variables y devolvió 26 lo cual es correcto ahora no se como lograr lo mismo pero con las variables dadas por el usuario

Ese es mi problema

Comment: ahi veo capas encuentre algo interesante en esa libreria

Comment: Pon los detalles de tu problema _en la pregunta_. Pulsa en [edit] y agrega lo que has mencionado en tus comentarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que es fácil, pero eso si, tendrías que tener un array con todas las letras y en este caso solo iteras en ese array y compruebas si la letra es igual al caracter en el que estamos en el array y si es así retornamos un número, que sería la posición en la que se encuentra y lo mismo para el otro número, al ya tener ambos número (posiciones), solo restamos y obtendremos cual es la diferencia entre estos.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h> //utilizamos la libreria que te dejaron en los comentarios

int buscar(char c);
int buscar(char c) {
    char abc[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','\0'}; 
    int len = sizeof(abc)/sizeof(abc[0]); //obtenemos el tamaño del array
    for (int x = 0; x < len; x++) { //recorremos
        if (abc[x] == c) return x; //retornamos la posición
    }
    return -1; //en caso no se encuentre
}
```

Nuestra función `buscar` busca el caracter pasado como argumento en la lista `abc` que es nuestro *abecedario*, Teniendo esto tu programa ya estaría listo, pero para *no diferenciar* entre mayúsculas y minúsculas simplemente podemos convertir el caracter en minúscula, gracias a la librería `ctype`, la cual tiene la función `tolower()`.

```c
int main(){
    char caracter1,caracter2;

    printf("Ingrese un caracter: ");
    scanf(" %c",&caracter1);

    printf("Ingrese otro caracter: ");
    scanf(" %c",&caracter2);
    
    int b1 = buscar(tolower(caracter1)); //obtenemos la posicion de la primera letra
    int b2 = buscar(tolower(caracter2)); //obtenemos la posicion de la segunda letra
    if (b1 !=-1 && b2!=-1){ //solo si la letra existe
        printf("la diferencia es : %d\n",b2-b1); //restamos b2 con b1
    }else{
        printf("La letra no existe");
    }
    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**resultado**

```
Ingrese un caracter: a
Ingrese otro caracter: f
la diferencia es : 5
```

La diferencia es teniendo en cuenta uno de los caracteres, por ejemplo : `b,c,d,e,f` donde hay 5 caracteres, pues la `a` no es considerada, si quieres le puedes retar 1 al resultado para solo hallar el numero de letras que hay entre estas 2.

Comment: ahora lo veo mas claro la verdad que gracias y me voy a anotar el tema de la librería nueva es muy practica en estas circunstancias

Bueno ahora le voy a agregar las funcionalidades que solicita el programa y creo que al fin puedo entregar todos mis trabajos 

Gracias a todos los que me orientaron

Comment: no te preocupes, muchos empezamos así. Trata de dividir tu problema en cosas sencillas :D

Comment: si se menciona mucho la abstracción de las cosas en Poo pero aplica para todo por lo visto jajaj

Gracias por la paciencia buen resto de jornada